# change text color in flutter SearchBar

Tags: flutter

I use the UI graphical librairie https://www.getwidget.dev/
I want to change the colors of the text in the search bar (https://docs.getwidget.dev/gf-searchbar/) , can someone explain me the parameter to change in this case...

I try this

```
GFSearchBar(
            searchBoxInputDecoration: const InputDecoration(
             prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
             suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
             ),
            searchList: [],
            onItemSelected: (item){},
            overlaySearchListItemBuilder: (item) { return Text('test'); }, 
            searchQueryBuilder: (String query, List<dynamic> list) { return ['test']; },
          ),
```

Thanks

Comment: `searchBoxInputDecoration` seems likely to be the right parameter in this case.

Comment: Thanks but it's not worked

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to change the `GFSearchBar` text color from `Colors.grey[600]`. This color [is hardcoded in the source-code](https://github.com/ionicfirebaseapp/getwidget/blob/abeba46df7c23895048303c24523b25c966d0fed/lib/components/search_bar/gf_search_bar.dart#L150).

At least it's open source and the change is minimal. You can even propose a PR for this change.

To install a local package, point the `pubspec.yaml` dependency to the path downloaded from GitHub.

Instead of:

```yaml
dependencies:
  ...
  getwidget: ^3.0.1
```

Do this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  ...
  getwidget:
    path: /path/to/the/downloaded/package/getwidget
```

Here's the result by changing the color to `Colors.red`.

[image: Screenshot]